# Do some tasks after a simplenews newsletter has been sent

Tags: emails, notifications

I need to unsubscribe users from a specific simplenews newsletter category after a newsletter of that category has been sent. The best way is to do this action after updating sent status of newsletter. but there are not a hook or event to do this. What is your opinion to implement this task?

Comment: Did you try using rules. I hope `simplenews` integrates with rules.

Comment: Simplenews only provides two events in rules: when a single user subscribes or unsubscribes.

Comment: Currently, I remove subscriptions in hook_simplenews_spooled. But it is not a good way to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be patch simplenews to offer more events.

Second best would be to override simplenews via a custom module to offer more events.

There are other options but those are the best following the Drupal way.